# Button not sticking next to field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position my button so it sticks next to the input field.

Like here:

[image]

In the example i just showed there, the button had a position relative and a float right. I did the exact same thing but it didn't work.

Here is my fiddlesticks:

```css
.subscribe input {
  font: 15px/25px Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.subscribe button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 53px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.textboxwhite-left {
  padding: 40px 20px 0px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left !important;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="textboxwhite-left">
    <form class="subscribe" action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="subscribefield" required="true" placeholder="Awe" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow i cannot add jsfiddle to my post I will post it here! https://jsfiddle.net/up6xxxr5/

Comment: you can also make snippet of it.

Comment: when you ask question in editor there are some options on top.. then choose 7th option. you will get it. :)

Comment: I'm making a responsive website the width has to be 100%. @nevermind and also this is irrelevant for my problem so yeah

Comment: It kind of is...... @nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you?

```
.subscribe{ display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code.

```css
.subscribe input {
  font: 15px/25px Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left: 10px;
   float: left;
}

.subscribe button {
  height: 46px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.textboxwhite-left {
  padding: 40px 20px 0px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left !important;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="textboxwhite-left">

    <form class="subscribe" action="" method="post">


      <input type="text" name="subscribefield" required="true" placeholder="Awe" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

added **display:inline-block** to **.textboxwhite-left** and adjusted height and width of button according to input.

```css
.subscribe input {
  font: 15px/25px Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.subscribe button {
  height: 46px;
  width: 58px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.textboxwhite-left {
  padding: 40px 20px 0px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left !important;
  display : inline-block;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="textboxwhite-left">
    <form class="subscribe" action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="subscribefield" required="true" placeholder="Awe" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="search">
  <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="serach here">
  <input class="submit" value="Seach">
  </form>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.search{
  position:relative;
  padding:0px 100px 10px 10px;
}
.search input[type="text"]{
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  display:block; 

}
.search input[type="text"]:focus{
      -webkit-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
       outline:none;
}
.search .submit{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  right:0;
  border:2px solid black;
  top:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search .submit:hover{
  background:black;color:#fff;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/jmc548vc/1/

Answer (score 1):

Please do have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up6xxxr5/3/).

```
.subscribe button {
  height: 46px;
  width: 53px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;                \\this is changed to absolute
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```